# Unable to delete object property in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

```
function remove(e){
    self.deletingId = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.id;
    for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(DataMixin.data.holidayList).length; i++){
        if(self.deletingId == DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1].reason){
            console.log('matched'); //prints on deletion of 5th object and then 3rd object as well
            delete DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1];
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
            console.log('ID deleted is: ' , DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1]); // still prints the value
        }
    }
}
```

Out of ten objects with key/value pairs, I deleted 5th object sucessfully and then deleting 3rd object is throwing error even though the if condition is satisfied:

Error here: `reason` is undefined at `DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1].reason`

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that when you delete an entry the array shortens (and hence you might get to try accessing an index that does not exist anymore)?

Comment: `delete` on array item set the item as `undefined`, it doesn't remove it from array. That's said, i'm lost getting your logic there, trying to delete `i+1`. A MCVE would help for sure. Maybe you should iterate in reverse order

Comment: @FDavidov I am calling remove function using `onclick` which should set the `i` value to 0 inside the loop right?

Comment: What you need to do is to use the `splice` method (which fully remove an object from an array) and, instead of looping using a `for` construct, change it such that you would exit before you attempt to access an object with an index outside the new range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me (Object.keys(DataMixin.data.holidayList).length - 1) is the last property key in the DataMixin.data.holidayList, so if you do DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1], at the loop end, if will not find the object property.

Comment: but object `DataMixin.data.holidayList` index is starting from 1 so that's why I am doing `i+1`